# What does "male spectacle" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Consider ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA13-PR94&dq=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20word%20search%2034&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1yoSHmb7NAhUEEJoKHW8_BzkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=male%20spectacle&f=false)):

> What sport requires the timing of tennis, the stamina of cross-country running, and physical contact of football? The answer is: Boxing. And now that seemingly **male spectacle** is attracting women.

Does ***male spectacle*** mean dominated by men?

Comment: Compare "Hunting is a predominantly male activity".  Most of those who engage in the activity are male. Most of audience for boxing has traditionally been male. Male spectacle is like student housing.  Spectacle (deemed) appropriate to, or for males; housing for students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary sense of **male** denotes the sex of an animal, as an adjective: men, boys, rams, bulls, and peacocks are all **male**; women, girls, ewes, cows, and peahens are all **female**.*

The sentence that you are asking about uses **male** in an extended sense. Since boxing is not an animal, you can safely infer that the author wants you to understand **male** not in its primary sense, but in some way *related to* its primary sense. You must infer the exact meaning from context.

In this case, **male spectacle** means an activity that men, but not women, perform, which creates a visually conspicuous show that attracts other people's attention (a "spectacle"). This usage of **male** is similar to its meaning in **[male display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtship_display#Male_display)**, referring to things like the spreading of a peacock's [tail feathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peafowl#/media/File:Paonroue.JPG). The display is not itself literally male. The display is an action distinctive to males of that species; the females don't do it.

I don't understand the word **male** in this context to mean **male-dominated**, though the meanings are somewhat ambiguous. The primary (though rare) sense of **dominate** is to hold power over someone; a common secondary sense is to exist in the greatest number or proportion in some area. If thousands of women took up boxing, they would still be outnumbered by male boxers, and so the sport would still be male-dominated in that secondary sense. Men might still control the sport, too, so it would still be male-dominated in the primary sense. I understand **male spectacle** in the quoted sentence to regard boxing as something like the peacock's tail display: an activity performed exclusively by men. However, the phrase and context are not fully clear about this, and I doubt that the author thought about it carefully.

Note that, in this context, there is a slight difference in meaning between **male spectacle** and **masculine spectacle**. **Masculine** denotes the qualities distinctively associated with maleness, but not maleness itself. It's not a self-contradiction to say that a certain woman has some masculine qualities—for example, a deep voice, or an urge to get into fistfights. Through the choice of the word **male** or **masculine**, the author guides the reader to understand the phrase by extending one primary sense or the other: the male sex, or the qualities associated with it. The choice of **male** rather than **masculine** agrees with the author's meaning of "Boxing was formerly performed only by men, but now women are starting to box, too."

---

* <sub>By the way, English has a peculiar ambiguity regarding the words **animal**, **man**, **cow**, and **peacock**. One sense of **animal** is any organism that moves itself from place to place and has consciousness, human or otherwise; another sense of **animal** means only non-human animals. One sense of **man** includes humans of both sexes; another sense, much more common, means only male humans. One sense of **cow** includes all animals of the genus *[Bos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bos);* another sense means only females of the genus *Bos.* Even the word **peacock** commonly refers to both sexes of the [peafowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peafowl), despite the fact that **-cock** specifically designates a male bird. The word **peacock** is well-known, **peahen** is not well-known, and **peafowl** is almost unheard-of in everyday English.</sub>

Comment: Many thanks for the thorough answer. So, you say using **masculine** is more focused on a male's specifications and **male** is a more general term. Therefore, author tried to avoid obsessing the reader with details, conveying the meaning as fast as possible.

Comment: @Cardinal Actually, I think that the author was trying to avoid suggesting that boxing is _unfeminine._ I wouldn't say that **male** is more general than **masculine**. **Male** just means the one sex rather than the other. **Masculine** is hazier, referring vaguely to traits associated with maleness. People often say that one person is _more_ masculine than another. Notice the use of **male** and **masculine** [here](http://facelab.org/debruine/Publications/masctech). It requires a longer extension from the primary sense of **male** to speak of degrees of maleness.

Answer (score 2):

> a spectacle

is an event which attracts a lot of attention

> a male spectacle

is a spectacle involving male participants

In your passage, "male spectacle", means it has male participants so in that sense it is "dominated by men".

Recently, boxing has been attracting females into the arena.  Mohammad Ali's daughter is a boxer.  So far, there have not been any officially sanctioned mixed fights that I am aware of.

As a synonymous intensifier

> spectacular

might be used, as it can have a much more positive meaning than "spectacle"

> [Christmas Spectacular - Radio City Rockettes](https://www.rockettes.com/christmas/)